# How to use tabs contents in Nav bar Angular 5+?

Tags: angular, mat-tab

I have followed [this](https://www.nikhildevre.com/creating-tabs-using-angular-material-5-and-angular-5-routing/) tutorial for tabs in angular 5+.

Html:

```
<div style="padding: 5px;">
  <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link
       *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index;"
       [routerLink]="routeLink.link"
       routerLinkActive
       #rla="routerLinkActive"
       [active]="activeLinkIndex === i"
       (click)="activeLinkIndex = i"
       [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
       [class]=getActiveClass(i)>
      {{routeLink.label}}
    </a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I am new to angular and am not sure why all my contents are coming in my nav bar contents. Instead of my normal `Router-Outlet` in `app.component.html`.

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <app-nav-menu>Tabs goes here</app-nav-menu>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
      <router-outlet>My Main content usually comes here</router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My aim is to only have contents in the nav-bar that are specific to the tab(sub section) and my content displays in the main `Router-Outlet` as usual.

Comment: remove router-outlet from nav bar

Comment: To get what you want, you need to use an aux route, but that's even going to be difficult. I understand what you want, but I don't believe it's entirely possible in the way that you want it.

Comment: I remove the router-outlet and both main content and tab goes in my normal outlet. All I wanted my tab to do in the nav bar is to display a list of objects it doesn't have to be routed. After reading your comments I realised that I don't need the routes I just need to hide or show objects depending on the selected tab.(Or does tab have to be routed?)